# If statement always returns false

Tags: java, if-statement, minecraft, bukkit

I have a series of if statements that all seem to work except for when I reach two arguments after a command (Minecraft Bukkit server/API).  With two arguments it returns false no matter what.  I am using the command `/jukebox play 13` to test it.

Current code:

```
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandlabel, String[] args) {
            Player p = (Player) sender;
            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("jukebox")) {
                if (args.length == 0) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "** " + ChatColor.AQUA + "Jukebox version " + pdFile.getVersion() + ChatColor.GOLD + " **\n" + ChatColor.RED + "Usage: " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "/jukebox play (track)");
                return true;
                }
                if (args.length == 1) {
                    if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("play")) {
                        String recordNames = "Stop, 13, Cat, Blocks, Chirp, Far, Mall, Mellohi, Stal, Strad, Ward, 11, Wait";
                        String regex = "\\[|\\]";
                        recordNames = recordNames.replaceAll(regex, "");
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Track selection: " + ChatColor.GREEN + recordNames + "\n" + ChatColor.AQUA + "Type " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "/jukebox play (track)" + ChatColor.AQUA + " to play a track.");
                        return true;
                    }
                if (args.length == 2 && (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("play"))) {
                        if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("13")) {
                            p.playEffect(p.getLocation(), Effect.RECORD_PLAY, 2256);
                            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Now playing " + ChatColor.GREEN + "13" + ChatColor.AQUA + ".");
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Please enter a valid track name.");
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Does anyone see why it is returning false?  Just as a side note, if you see anything in here that could be coded more efficiently, feel free to suggest that too.

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Try printing `args` using `Arrays#toString` before to check how many arguments you really have.

Comment: It may be an artifact of the SO formatting or whoever formatted this code, but you would probably find your error if you employed a consistent indentation style for your `if` blocks. For some of them, you indent the block, and for others, you don't. I think that once you format everything nicely, your error will pop out at you. Hint: for every `{` after an `if`, find its corresponding `}`. One of them will be in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Your indention is throwing you off. Your closing braces are in the wrong place. Your args.length == 2 check is nested within the args.length ==1 check. At the minimum you will have to :
 1. add a closing brace before the if statement for args.length == 2 check
 2. delete a closing brace before the return false statement.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bracket is in the wrong place:

```
if (args.length == 1) {
    if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("play")) {
        String recordNames = "Stop, 13, Cat, Blocks, Chirp, Far, Mall, Mellohi, Stal, Strad, Ward, 11, Wait";
        String regex = "\\[|\\]";
        recordNames = recordNames.replaceAll(regex, "");
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Track selection: " + ChatColor.GREEN + recordNames + "\n" + ChatColor.AQUA + "Type " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "/jukebox play (track)" + ChatColor.AQUA + " to play a track.");
        return true;
    }
```

should be:

```
if (args.length == 1) {
    if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("play")) {
        String recordNames = "Stop, 13, Cat, Blocks, Chirp, Far, Mall, Mellohi, Stal, Strad, Ward, 11, Wait";
        String regex = "\\[|\\]";
        recordNames = recordNames.replaceAll(regex, "");
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Track selection: " + ChatColor.GREEN + recordNames + "\n" + ChatColor.AQUA + "Type " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "/jukebox play (track)" + ChatColor.AQUA + " to play a track.");
        return true;
    }
}
```

notice the `}` at the end. Right now, you're code is doing this:

```
if(args.length == 1){
    if(args.length > 1 && args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("play")){
    }
}
```

which will always return false, as `args` cannot have a length of one, and also have a length greater than one

Answer (score 1):

As other's have said, you've gotten the bracket nesting wrong, and your incorrect code indentation is misleading you.

Advice ... if you want to avoid this kind of problem in the future:

1. Pay more attention to your code style in general, and particularly indentation.  It makes your code easier for >>you<< to read.
2. Use an IDE ... or a smart editor that is capable of correctly indenting Java.  And make sure that you make use of its auto-indenting functionality.
3. If possible, configure your IDE / editor to use space characters not TAB characters for code indentation.  If your code has TAB characters in it, then it will look different (i.e. incorrectly indented) on different systems.

Answer (score 0):

As **shoover** pointed out the `}` for the `if (args.length == 1)` statement was in the wrong place.

**The new code is:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandlabel, String[] args) {
            Player p = (Player) sender;
            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("jukebox")) {
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "** " + ChatColor.AQUA + "Jukebox version " + pdFile.getVersion() + ChatColor.GOLD + " **\n" + ChatColor.RED + "Usage: " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "/jukebox play (track)");
                    return true;
                }
                if (args.length == 1) {
                    if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("play")) {
                        String recordNames = "Stop, 13, Cat, Blocks, Chirp, Far, Mall, Mellohi, Stal, Strad, Ward, 11, Wait";
                        String regex = "\\[|\\]";
                        recordNames = recordNames.replaceAll(regex, "");
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Track selection: " + ChatColor.GREEN + recordNames + "\n" + ChatColor.AQUA + "Type " + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "/jukebox play (track)" + ChatColor.AQUA + " to play a track.");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                if (args.length > 1 && (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("play"))) {
                    if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("13")) {
                        p.playEffect(p.getLocation(), Effect.RECORD_PLAY, 2256);
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Now playing " + ChatColor.GREEN + "13" + ChatColor.AQUA + ".");
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Please enter a valid track name.");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        return false;
```